# Postgres select distinct based on timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with two columns a and b where a is an ID and b is a timestamp.
I need to select all of the a's which are distinct but I only care about the most up to date row per ID.

I.e. I need a way of selecting distinct a's conditional on the b values.

Is there a way to do this using DISTINCT ON in postgres?

Cheers

Comment: `select distinct on (a) a,b from the_table order by a, b desc`?

Comment: Most up to date: `select * from ztable t where not exists (select * from ztable x where x.a = t.a and x.b > t.b);`

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name - will the ordering be applied before or after the DISTINCT? @joop could you explain how that works please and I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: @JMzance: the order is _used_ to find the distinct values. It is essential for `distinct on ()` to work properly. Have a look at all the other questions tagged with [greatest-n-per-group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+postgresql) for Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @a_horse_with_no_name suggests, the solution is

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a) a, b FROM the_table ORDER BY a, b DESC
```

As [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-DISTINCT) says,

> Note that the "first row" of a set is unpredictable unless the query
>   is sorted on enough columns to guarantee a unique ordering of the rows
>   arriving at the `DISTINCT` filter. (`DISTINCT ON` processing occurs after
>   `ORDER BY` sorting.)

Answer (score 1):

As posted by the upvoted answers, `SELECT DISTINCT ON (a) a, b FROM the_table ORDER BY a, b DESC` works on Postgre 12. However, I am posting this answer to highlight few important points:

1. The results will be sorted based on column a; not column b.
2. Within each result row, the most recent (highest value) for column b would be picked.
3. In case, someone wants to get the most recent value for column b on the entire result set, in sql, we can run : `SELECT MAX(b) from (SELECT DISTINCT ON (a) a, b FROM the_table ORDER BY a, b DESC)`.